# Drawing cartooned versions of this image

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

Is there some efficient way to draw something like this?

[image: sat]

I haven't seen any examples on Texample to use as a basis for this.

I would like to generate something similar to a CAD-rendering of this using TikZ. The level of detail does not have to be as involved. For example, the reflections on the flat panels could be removed.

Any pointers to start?

Comment: You'll probably want to make your request more specific.  "Cartoon" could mean "cute and imprecise".  By "cartoon" do you mean that you want something that might be created in a 3d CAD software?  Do you need reflections (or transparency) that is evident in the flat panels?  For that, you could use a ray tracing program such as POV-Ray.

Comment: @James, good point, I've edited the OP

Comment: I think that there are no magical tricks that can generate the cartoon just so. That is, a complete reproduction of the diagram will be tedious. From that perspective it might make more sense to ask questions on certain steps. (Ironically the reflection is not the most difficult part, it can be achieved rather easily with path fading, already the cover of the pgfmanual has examples.)

Comment: I don't think drawing this in TikZ is a good idea. Fundamentally, TikZ is a 2D engine. When one draws 3D objects, the occlusion between objects needs to be taken into account. Since TikZ does not have 3D support such as z-buffer, it is very difficult to draw something like this.

Comment: I use Inkscape for such things. Import the image and put it on it's own layer. Then you draw a vector graphic.

Comment: You might have luck with "fuzzy select"  but you will probably have to "free select" the reflections.